# Как выводить данные на верх JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть код:

```
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey) {
  var order = snapshot.val();

  //выводим заказы
   var ul = document.getElementById('orders');
docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "col-md-2 col-masonry product";
  //div.style.position = "relative";
  div.innerHTML = '<h5 class="product-title">' + order.name +'</h5><br>'+ order.phone +'<br>';
  docfrag.appendChild(div);

ul.appendChild(docfrag);
});
```

Который выводит новые данные в низ страницы, как сделать что бы он выводил новые данные в  верх а не в низ страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Упрощенный вид:

```js
var ul = document.getElementById('myUl');
var div = document.createElement("div");
//div.style.position = "relative";
div.innerHTML = '<li>Some before text</li>';
ul.insertBefore(div, ul.children[0]);
```

```html
<ul id="myUl">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Индекс `0` в строке `ul.insertBefore(div, ul.children[0]);` говорит о том, перед каким элементов вставлять новый.

[Ссылка на документацию](https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document)